# Text on hover overflows doesn't align within <a>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

We have several tiles that we want to use to display some text. On hover of each tile, we would like a hidden `<div>` element to show. However, we are finding that the text is overflowing and not aligning properly when used inside an `<a>` tag.

**Question:**

How can we keep the text from overflowing within the `<a>` element?

**Current output:**
[image: on hover issue]

**Desired output:**
[image: on hover fix]

**What we tried, but didn't work**

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex__col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px;
 position: relative;
}

.flex__link:hover > .flex__text__wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.flex__text__wrapper {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding: 8px;
}

.flex__text {
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container">
 <div class="flex__col">
   <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
     <div>Data Sheet</div>
     <div>Progressively fabricate market-driven</div>
     <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
       <div class="flex__text">
       Compellingly plagiarize interoperable bandwidth whereas holistic content.
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
   <div class="flex__col">
   <a href="#test"  class="flex__link">
     <div>Data Sheet</div>
     <div>methodologies rather than</div>
     <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
       <div class="flex__text">
       Single, Optimized System Improves Productivity
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
   <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
     <div>Data Sheet</div>
     <div>resource sucking schemas. Energistically initiate</div>
     <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
       <div class="flex__text">
       Complete operational and commercial readiness.
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
   <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
     <div>Data Sheet</div>
     <div>Seamlessly optimize empowered</div>
     <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
       <div class="flex__text">
       Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability. Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability. Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability.
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

- We tried setting a fixed height on the `flex__col` element, but because the text varies within the `flex__text` element, it was hard to find a value that works. We would prefer to be able to get the desire result where anything that overflows would just not be shown instead of showing lightly as shown under `current output`.

Comment: Consider use of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss on what element?

Comment: simply add `overflow:hidden` to `flex__text__wrapper`

Comment: To follow up, this would be on the `<div class="flex__text">` since that contains the text you wish to apply the ellipsis to - not sure how that would work with the wrapped text but that is likely a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an outer `div` around your `.flex__text` `div`, give it `height: 100%; overflow: hidden;`

I've added it just to the last one where your issue was.

```css
.flex__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex__col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex__link:hover>.flex__text__wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flex__text__wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}

.flex__text__outer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex__text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__container">
  <div class="flex__col">
    <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
      <div>Data Sheet</div>
      <div>Progressively fabricate market-driven</div>
      <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
        <div class="flex__text">
          Compellingly plagiarize interoperable bandwidth whereas holistic content.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
      <div>Data Sheet</div>
      <div>methodologies rather than</div>
      <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
        <div class="flex__text">
          Single, Optimized System Improves Productivity
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
      <div>Data Sheet</div>
      <div>resource sucking schemas. Energistically initiate</div>
      <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
        <div class="flex__text">
          Complete operational and commercial readiness.
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__col">
    <a href="#test" class="flex__link">
      <div>Data Sheet</div>
      <div>Seamlessly optimize empowered</div>
      <div class="flex__text__wrapper flex__white bkg--black">
        <div class="flex__text__outer">
          <div class="flex__text">
            Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability. Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability. Maximize productivity and protect roaming and interconnection business profitability.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```